# Terminal in Sublime Text?

Tags: plugins, emacs, editor, sublimetext2

I've a little question:

I have been working for 2 years with Sublime Text and it wonders me if there is a way to add a terminal in Sublime Text like Emacs does?

Comment: I prefer free stuff too, but I'm not sure how time invested in paid tools equals time wasted. De gustibus non est disputandum.

Answer (score 0):

In package control you can install Glue or SublimeRepl. There are many other options but those are the 2 I use the most.